# Что быстрее: std::vector или std::array?

Tags: c++, массивы, производительность, stl, vector

Стоит вопрос выбора внутреннего контейнера в классе.

Длина контейнера после инициализации меняться не будет.
В теории класс реализует n-мерную модель, но на практике размерность не будет превышать 4.

Я понимаю, что заметной разницы не будет, но с точки зрения внутреннего строения этих классов - что быстрее: обращения к элементам `std::array` или к элементам `std::vector`?

Comment: по произодительности одинаково. С токи зрения читабельности лучше array (акцентирует на фиксированном размере).

Comment: Любопытно просто: а зачем для размера в 4 элемента вообще что-то из `std::`?

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с [алгоритмом выбора контейнера](https://habrahabr.ru/company/infopulse/blog/194726/).

Comment: @PinkTux скажем так. В теории класс n-мерный, но на практике намного чаще используются размерности от 2 до 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше `std::array` - у него нет никаких накладных расходов типа выделения/перераспределения памяти, хранения количества элементов и т.п.